# exe file does not work inside the dist folder or outside it

Tags: python, exe

Hello everyone I have this code in python for 'file organization' the code is working without any problems

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil
import pathlib

temp_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
path = pathlib.PureWindowsPath(fr'{temp_path}').as_posix()
all_files = list()
extension = set()

#list of all the files and extensions
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file() and not fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, '*.ini'):
        all_files.append(entry.name)
        extension.add(os.path.splitext(entry)[1])

#creating the folders
for folder in extension:
    folder_path = path+'/All_'+folder[1:]+'s/'
    #creating the folder
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
    #check in the list of the files
    for file in all_files:
        if file.endswith(folder):
            #moving the file from the current directory to the directory
            shutil.move(path+'/'+file, folder_path+file)
```

The code supposed to take the files and organize them in folders depending on their extension, when I run the exe file it doesn't do this mission, the cmd window open for like on second and close and the files don't get organized
I've tried all the possible ways: pyInstaller --onefile, Py2exe, auto-py-to-exe, and more....
it doesn't work inside the dist folder or outside it when I create a shorcut and move to another directory, does anyone know what is the problem.
MY system is: Windows10

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very helpful.  What, exactly, happens?  Do you get an error?

Comment: And by the way, `fr'{temp_path}'` is exactly the same as writing `temp_path`.  Just use the variable.

Comment: @TimRoberts The code supposed to take the files and organize them in folders depending on their extension, when I run the exe file it doesn't do this mission, the cmd window open for like on second and close and  the files don't get organized

Comment: Have you printed out `temp_path` so you can see what path you're actually processing?  With an installer-built exe, the script might not be in the directory you think it is.  When your exe runs, it isn't like a compiled program.  Instead, it unzip a miniature Python environment of its own, including a copy of Python, then runs the interpreter.  That means your script might be in a temp directory.  It would be better for you to pass the target path as the first parameter.

Comment: Here's the pyinstaller documentation about the behavior of `__file__` in a bundled package https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html#:~:text=for%20these%20uses.-,Using%20__file__,relative%20to%20the%20bundle%20folder.